# Facebook Audience network upgrade with cocoapods does not upgrade to version 4.23

Tags: facebook, swift3

When i try to update the SDK via cocoapods it updates only up to version 4.20.1.
Does anyone know if there is a different cocoa pods line instead of " pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'"  or else how can i update the SDK version?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple. Instead of running in Terminal the

> pod install

i should have used

> pod update

this solved the problem.

[image: the result]